# jQuery animation works with only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

- I need to make it working for all my elements under Which nothing should fade (images).
- Currently works only for the `div.logo` tag

I guess at the moment the reason mine `<h1>` element is now allowing animations underneath is that when I am getting the `.top()`, `.left()` and so on, you are doing it for the last element in the list.

I need to get the borders of each element in the resulting list.

Any help would be much appreciated

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z9b8S/

JS:

```
function displayThese(selectorString) {
    var $heading = $(selectorString);
    var h1top = $heading.position().top;
    var h1bottom = h1top + $heading.height();
    var h1left = $heading.position().left;
    var h1right = h1top + $heading.width();

    var divs = $('li').filter(function () {
        var $e = $(this);
        var top = $e.position().top;
        var bottom = top + $e.height();
        var left = $e.position().left;
        var right = left + $e.width();

        return top > h1bottom || bottom < h1top || left > h1right || right < h1left;
    });
    return divs;
}

(function fadeInDiv() {
    var divsToChange = displayThese('h1, div.logo');
    var elem = divsToChange.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divsToChange.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.prev().remove();
        elem.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);
    } else {

        elem.animate({
            opacity: (Math.random() * 1)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function () {
            window.setTimeout(fadeInDiv);
        });
    }

})();

$(window).resize(function () {
    // Get items that do not change    
    var divs = $('li').not(displayThese());
    divs.css({
        opacity: 0.3
    });
});
```

Comment: do you want to be dynamic(no animation) for first row elements, no matter how many images are there ?

Comment: Also, in the window.resize function you are not passing arguments to the `displayThese()` function.

Comment: @Ani are you there? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @Ani I want to be able on the h1 and on the logo to stop the animation behind.

Comment: @Ani but at the moment works only with one! or h1 or Logo. I guess I need an each function somewhere but not sure.